# Codeigniter, PHP: Getting Object not found Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

When submitting a form, I am getting  an error

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. 
The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. 
Please inform the author of that page about the error. 
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster 
Error 404 localhost
04/27/12 15:30:23
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Url is being displayed as `http://localhost/frame/localhost/frame/index.php/verifylogin`.

Url is appended with `localhost/frame/` twice. I don't know what went wrong.

code in `config.php` is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/frame/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/frame/';
```

or if it will fail,

```
$config['base_url'] = '/';
```